# Magento 2: check customer logged in by javascript use model

Tags: magento2, javascript, customer-session, authorize

Just wanna to check if customer logged in by `javascript` use

> Magento_Customer/js/model/customer.

I've included following js file in module:

```
define([
    "jquery",
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
], function($, customer) {

    'use strict';

    $.widget('conv.bolPrices', {
        _init: function init() {
            console.log('customer', customer);
            console.log('Logged in', customer.isLoggedIn()); //getting undefined
        },

    });

    return $.conv.bolPrices;
});
```

After login, every time when I am loading page I am getting undefined value, instead true/false.

I wanna to do it use `model/customer`. I cleared `cache`, removed `generated/*`, etc, read a lot of topics about this theme, but had no success.

I very appreciate any help and advice. Thanks.

Comment: please try : https://gist.github.com/pawankparmar/621425df47fee5815251b8e6046487f1

Comment: thanks, not solution, because i use page_cache :) the issue still actual

Comment: Hi Denissio, could you add some clarification as to how the answer that you checked as correct help you to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

customer.isLoggedIn() is a `ko.obervable` on `window.isCustomerLoggedIn` and it seems that window.isCustomerLoggedIn is set by default only in the checkout templates:
module-checkout in onepage.phtml and cart/shipping.phtml and module-multishipping in checkout/billing.phtml

So one approach could be to add a similar functionality in some appropriate template and assign `Magento\Customer\Model\Session->isLoggedIn()` to `window.isCustomerLoggedIn` in case that
`window.isCustomerLoggedIn` is not defined. Maybe it works in footer template.

One more thought on this issue: If you are using caching (what you most likely do) you should move that to an uncached part if your cache key does not consider if customer is logged in or not.

Comment: customer.isLoggedIn() rerturns undefined,
but customer.isLoggedIn returns following:


Customer loggedIn ƒ observable() {
        if (arguments.length > 0) {
            // Write

            // Ignore writes if the value hasn't changed
            if (observable.isDifferent(_latestValue, arguments[0])) {…
product-5:1

Comment: and even from customer.isLoggedIn I cannot get the customer status

Comment: https://i109.fastpic.ru/big/2019/0228/66/9565b8fd6225b48b42632792d499a966.png

Comment: Ok, sorry for the first answer. I've checked the code of the js model and isLoggedIn is a `ko.obervable` on `window.isCustomerLoggedIn`, so your approach to get the data using `customer.isLoggedIn()` is correct. 
I've updated my answer with what I found out.

Answer (score 0):

Takes time to populate customer info into CustomerData.

Try the following code:

```
var self = this;
var counter = 0;
var timeTopMenu = setInterval(function () {

    self.customer = customerData.get('customer');

    if (self.customer().fullname != undefined) {
        // custom code here
        clearInterval(timeTopMenu);
    } else {
        counter++;
        if(counter > 5) {
            clearInterval(timeTopMenu);
        }
    }
}, 1000);
```