# Cache breaks my check for detecting if a customer is logged in

Tags: magento2, customer, cache

When I turned off cache (bin/magento cache:disable) the below code works otherwise it's not working.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    echo "logged in";
}else{
    echo "no logged";
}
```

Comment: bin/magento cache:disable  if i go guest i got no logged if i go customer i got loged.
bin/magento cache:enable if i go guest i got no loged if go customer ig ot no loged

Comment: The response is just getting cached. Itt will work on first load however remain the same for each request thereafter if that is what you are experiencing. There are Javascript alternatives for this that will work https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263905/magento-2-check-customer-logged-in-by-javascript-use-model

Comment: You **can NOT** use the code like this. where you want to use  check customer session?

Answer (score 0):

The block responsible for rendering the template which contains the logic above is cached.

Couple of options

To disable caching of custom block on a Magento 2 product view page, you can implement a couple of different approaches:

In a layout, set cacheable=”false”. Note that this attribute will make the whole page non-cacheable.

Alternatively, you can set _isScopePrivate property to true in a block class. By implementing this approach, you instruct a page cache module to replace your block content with placeholder before caching. When the page is loaded from cache, your block can be rendered via Ajax request. Check \Magento\Captcha\Block\Captcha::__construct and related layouts/templates as an example.